# ES6 modules via script tag has the error "The requested module does not provide an export named 'default' "

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, umd

I tried to [import a module](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) via script tag,

```
<script type="module">
        import phonebar from "https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar.js"
```

I got the error

> The requested module
>   'https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar.js' does not provide an
>   export named 'default'

I changed it to so-called "Import a module for its side effects only" and it worked as expected.

```
 <script type="module">
        import "https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar.js"
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) said `import '/modules/my-module.js';` is to

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing
>   anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually
>   import any values.

Those words did not make sense to me. 
Beside, if I use npm+webpack to set up a simple project. `npm i jssip-emicnet` then I can import phonebar correctly in my js code.

```
import phonebar from 'jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar';
```

So why can't I import it via `<script>` tag in browser?

I am actually the author of jssip-emicnet. The `phone.js` is like this

```
class Phone {
  ...
}
export default Phone
```

And my webpack output setting is this

```
entry: {
    phonebar: './src/ui/phone.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    library: '[name]'
},
```

So I am not sure if it is because I miss something about my webpack setting.

----- update -----

With the comments I got I found this [Output an ES module using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289200/output-an-es-module-using-webpack)

The question was about webpack 2 and I am using webpack 4 but since this issue is still open https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933 maybe webpack has not supported that yet.

[UMD is not compatible with JavaScript modules](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/issues/124) also helps to explain umd and es6 module.

Comment: `libraryTarget: 'umd'` means that you are no longer generating an ES6 module. It doesn't have any `export` declarations that can be imported using module syntax.

Comment: If you use webpack, it generates a compatibility wrapper around imports so that you can also import scripts with other module formats, not just ES6 modules.

Comment: So how do I generate an ES6 module ?

Comment: Dunno, `libraryTarget: 'es6'` would be my guess, but I haven't checked the docs? If webpack doesn't work for you, use rollup, which definitely supports ES6 modules.

Answer (score 2):

**At first I thought your import was incorrect**

The name of your default export is `Phone`.

```
class Phone {
  ...
}
export default Phone
```

In your code you are requesting the `phonebar` variable from your module, which is not the default export value. This will throw an error.
Try changing the `phonebar` import value to the name of the default class.

See example below.

```
import Phone from "https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar.js"
```

**But then I took a look at your `phonebar.js` file**

It seems that the code you import from the URL has been *transpiled*, meaning that it no longer works with `import` and `export` like you try to do. Click [here](https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet@1.2.8/dist/phonebar.js) to see the raw representation of your code and search for `export default` and see, there is no such thing. And that causes the errors.

I would recommend that, if possible, you would import the `src` or development version of your `phonebar.js` script.

Or don't use a module and load in the script the standard way.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but you did not answer my question. Besides if it "meaning that it no longer works with import and export like you try to do." See my word about "import phonebar from 'jssip-emicnet/dist/phonebar';"

Comment: check my updated question about why it was called phonebar

Comment: I've installed your package and compared it to the `unpkg.com` file. There seem to be differences in the code. So maybe that's why it is working when you install it, but not when you download it.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier actually, Qiulang's code does work with es modules, it just defines the esModule property to export. See this page: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Comment: Awesome. "export default foo" - this line helped me. I was getting the same error because of "module.exports = foo"

Answer (score 0):

It's far from obvious for a first time ts/js npm library developer that webpack uses series of optimizations by default that remove a lot of code that it determines unused.

When creating a library, wepack needs to be told explicitly so it does not remove your exports:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/